# Animation: How to make circle/ball move straight down the y-axis

Tags: java, animation, graphics, sleep, motion

I'm trying to get the red dot to move straight down the y-axis. Please help. Right now it is not moving. I need it to move down at x = 235, y = 0 Until x = 235, y = 235 to create the illusion of motion. Here is the code (it is messy because I changed the ball movement from left right, but can't get it to got downward).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Animation {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(350, 350);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        background(g);
        ballroll(panel, g);
    }
    public static void ballroll(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
        //draw and roll the ball now
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        int x = 245, y = 0, direction=1;
        while(y<245){
            g.fillOval(235, 0, 20, 20);
            //if (x==0){
                y+=60;
                direction *= -1;
            }
            //else if (x < 115){
                //direction *= -1;
                //y+=60;
            //}
            y+=direction*15;
            System.out.println(x);
            panel.sleep(80);

        }
        panel.sleep(350);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animation: how to "roll" circle down the y-axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582775/animation-how-to-roll-circle-down-the-y-axis)

Comment: do not post duplicate questions instead add the new info as edit to your original question

Answer (score 0):

You counting the `y` value up but you didn't use it.
I think it should be `g.fillOval(235, y, 20, 20);`